# Im trying to make snake and this isnt working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im using python and it says invalid syntax and highlights the semicolon how do I fix it?

```
self.updateCount = self.updateCount + 1
    if self.updateCount &gt; self.updateCountMax:
        for i in range(self.length-1, 0, -1):
            self.x[i] = self.x[i-1]
            self.y[i] = self.y[i-1]
```

Comment: What do you expect `&gt;` to do? That isn't valid python.

Answer (score 0):

You copy and paste you code from web-site, right?
Simple replace

```
&gt;
```

by

```
>
```

and andjoy :)